# Nginx Php-fpm not logging 500 error anywhere

Tags: nginx, php

Nor do nginx or php-fpm reports a error 500 output, In fact the 500 response is on the access log and not on the nginx error log. The script is running ok in my dev environment.

```
nginx version: nginx/1.6.2  
PHP 5.5.19 (fpm-fcgi)
```

Tried this

```
catch_workers_output = 1
```

Restarted everything, still not working

nginx access log shows:

```
x.x.x.x - - [12/Dec/2014:19:25:08 -0200] "GET /merchant/customer/mobile/data?sEcho=1&iColumns=3&sColumns=%2C%2C&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=10&mDataProp_0=0&sSearch_0=&bRegex_0=false&bSearchable_0=true&mDataProp_1=1&sSearch_1=&bRegex_1=false&bSearchable_1=true&mDataProp_2=2&sSearch_2=&bRegex_2=false&bSearchable_2=true&sSearch=&bRegex=false&_=1418418256370 HTTP/1.1" 500 589 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36"
```

Note the 500 error, which should be on error.log and with the php trace that's is happening on other errors.

Any clues?

Answer (score 12):

When PHP display_errors are disabled, PHP errors can return Nginx 500 error.

Take a look into your php-fpm logs, i'm sure you'll find the error there. With CentOS 7 :

```
tail -f /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
```

You can finally show PHP errors. In /etc/php.ini, change :

```
display_errors = Off
```

to :

```
display_errors = On
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

In case it helps someone else (Google brought me here), I had a similar problem (although in Apache, not nginx).

An older app I was installing was giving a 500 error with no output anywhere, in spite of every conceivable error logging setting turned to the most verbose level.

It turns out the problem was the controversial [error-control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php), "@". As the red warning box in the docs states, no matter how verbose your logging is, if an @-prefixed command causes PHP to stop because of a typo, or because it is not available (say, because you have forgotten to install a critical module like php-mysql), PHP will exit with absolutely no indication as to why.

So, if you find yourself with a 500-error and no logs, check your codebase for "@" symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Verify php-fpm service is running

```
sudo service php-fpm status
```

This will display the hostnames that can execute php.

Next edit php.ini to display errors. this will display errors on page..to make things easy to diagnose

```
sudo vim /etc/php.ini
```

then hit key [/] and type

```
display_errors
```

hit key [i] user arrow keys and backspace to set display_errors = on

then restart php-fpm service

On system type redhat /centos etc..

```
sudo service php-fpm restart
```

Comment: sudo service php5-fpm status

Comment: `php5-fpm` in the above could be any number of things, you can use `service --status-all | grep "php"` to get a short list of possibilities.

Comment: You can also use wildcards `service php*-fpm status`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to see php-fpm error stack trace in nginx error log file ( by default /var/log/nginx/error.log) the enable

```
log_errors = On
```

if you want php-fpm error stack trace to see in browser then set

```
display_errors = On
```

Comment: People should be aware of the second point. +1
And for production errors should not be displayed in browser