# CodeIgniter's error log doesn't seem to report all errors

Tags: mysql, linux, nginx, codeigniter-3, php-7

I'm currently creating a web application through linux OS (debian), using php7, codeIgniter 3, Nginx and Mysql.

Few months ago, all my PHP errors used to be reported in the default nginx log error (located at : /var/log/nginx/)

But recently, I have configured CodeIgniter in purpose to report those errors inside the folder of my application.

It seemed to work, because I noticed that my current errors were repported in this new log file.
However, "some" errors don't seem to be reported. For example, I have a form in my web application, running aswell with Javascript (ajax use). Once I send the form, I can notice in my browser's console an Error 500 (internal server error). However, this error is not reported in my error log file ! (and I already checked in the former log file belonging to Nginx, there's nothing too)

What am I supposed to do ?

Thanks you.

Comment: You woudn't expect Codeigniter to log internal server errors as it's not running when that occurs. This might lead you in the right direction. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27452528/nginx-php-fpm-not-logging-500-error-anywhere

Comment: Ok, I applied modifications in my php.ini file (display_errors = on) but nothing seem to change. Also, I have added in my nginx configuration (/etc/nginx/sites-available/...) a specific error log file with level "warn". Unfortunately, the 500 error is still not logged :/

Comment: this may help , although it's for apache2 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/20511956/2359679

Comment: I applied those modifications too, still no error logged :/ thank you...